# Extract Data Between div Tags Beautifulsoup in Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I'm attempting to create a BeautifulSoup price web crawler. Below is what is shown from the website I'm interested in crawling.

```
<div class="product-total-price">
                        <span itemprop="price">$14.76</span>
```

The pricing "$14.76" is all I'm interested in. But when I attempt to return it

```
import bs4
import requests


def getPrice(productUrl):
    res = requests.get(productUrl)
    res.raise_for_status()
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
    return soup.select("div.product-total-price > span")[0].parent


price = getPrice('https://www.homedepot.ca/en/home/p.12-sheetrock-ultralight-drywall-gypsum-panel-4-x-12.1000149007.html')
print(price)
```

Output is:

-

I used .parent to see what's going

```
<div class="product-total-price">
<span itemprop="price">-</span>
```

And poof no pricing shown. I am new to programming and have attempted to research into this but have had no luck. Any assistance would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You're technically getting the correct answer back. The actual price `($14.76)` is not rendered until the page calls some javascript and that is what changes the page to show the actual price `($14.76)` and not the placeholder of `-`.  Read up on some of the ways to remedy this here: https://datapatterns.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes/scraping-beyond-the-basics.html#dealing-with-javascript

Comment: Thank you serk. I took a look into your link and found the solution. It's not ideal but it has helped me learn a little bit more. I used selenium in the end, I'll post the answer below. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

As you can see, there is a `-`, not a price.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by serk the page is not fully rendered with beautiful soup. That is why I was getting the response '-' because it is just a placeholder on the price until the page can calls some javascript. This is what in turn would change the pricing. Here is my workaround this

```
from selenium import webdriver

 browser = webdriver.Firefox()
 browser.get('https://www.homedepot.ca/en/home/p.12-sheetrock-ultralight-drywall-gypsum-panel-4-x-12.1000149007.html')
 elem = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('div.product-total-price > span')

 print(elem.text)
    **$14.76**
 browser.quit()
```

I used selenium to open a browser so that the price loads. This will open up a browser, it may not be perfect but it sure is better then the pricing being '-'.

**You can get selenium here http://www.seleniumhq.org/**